# checkbox auto checked item after remove item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

after remove item selected check box auto check next item.
i try to override getcount method but no result

> CountryAdapter.java

```
CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyCountry>{
Context context; int layoutResourceId;  ArrayList<MyCountry> countries; ContextualActionMode activity;
public CountryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<MyCountry> countries) {
}
@Override
public int getCount() { 
    return countries.size();
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MyCountry country = countries.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView == null) 
    {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
        viewHolder.nameEn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameEn);
        viewHolder.nameVi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameVi);
        viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFlag);
        viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else 
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    viewHolder.nameEn.setText(countries.get(position).getNameEn());
    viewHolder.nameVi.setText(countries.get(position).getNameVi());
    viewHolder.flag.setImageDrawable(countries.get(position).getFlag());
    viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            count = 0;
            for (MyCountry country : countries) {
                if(country.isCheck()) count++;
            }
            if(isChecked)
            {
                if(activity.actionMode == null || count == 0)
                activity.actionMode = activity.startActionMode(activity.callback);
                count++;
                country.setCheck(true);
            }
            else
            {
                country.setCheck(false);
                count--;
                if(count == 0) activity.actionMode.finish();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
int count = 0;
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView nameEn;
    TextView nameVi;
    ImageView flag;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

> ContextualActionMode.java

```
public class ContextualActionMode extends Activity {

ArrayList<MyCountry> countries = new ArrayList<MyCountry>();
ListView listView;
CountryAdapter adapter;
ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mnDelete:
            for (int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++)
            {
                if (countries.get(i).isCheck()) {
                     countries.remove(countries.get(i));
                                   countries.get(i).setChecked(false)
                             }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

maybe error here, i find some solutions, but nothing work
i try to change the loop, because the list start index from 0

// i can fix it, thank a lot to Armaan Stranger

link to my source for who has the same problem with me 
 mediafire.com/?agnvic06c69cvw0

and edit in CountryAdapter.java

```
viewHolder.flag.setImageDrawable(countries.get(position).getFlag());
viewHolder.check.setChecked(false); --> right here, i forgot to add set check false as default.
viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
```

Comment: sorry,couldn't got you. what do you want exactly. please explain little more.

Comment: sorry, i make an application show language of the country and a checkbox,
after check item, i will remove this item by button delete
but after remove item, checkbox auto check next item.
example: 3 item a b c, checked in item b, after remove item b, check box auto check item c

Comment: what's the problem do you have?? explain more about your problem.

Comment: the problem is the checkbox auto check next item. Sorry, i am not good at english.

Comment: ok. got it. you mean that when you remove checkbox item then it will select next item automatically.

Comment: yes, T.T thank so much T.T 
sorry about my language

Comment: what i think is that the problem is you are storing position of check box when it is checked. then you remove any checkbox item then the item will be removed but that position is set to next item so that its getting checked. so i think you need to remove the checked state of item as well.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I can't. The arraylist change the size per time remove item, how can refix it?

Comment: try to setChecked(false) for the item on that position then notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: yes, i try it first. But not work

Comment: when i try to set countries.get(i+1).setChecked(false)
a error show indexoutofboundsexception 
the last way i try,  i use a templist, and add all selected item into that, after delete button press, i remove this list, but the checked still there

Comment: don't get i+1. just use i.

Comment: i try but not work
do you want to look my full source?
maybe u can understand when see it and find the solution

Comment: okk... i will see that..

Comment: here : http://www.mediafire.com/?agnvic06c69cvw0
full source from my teacher :D 
thank a lot :D

Comment: i think i have solved that. you can check my answer. if it can solve your problem than accept it as answer and also upvote it so it can be helpful to others as well. cheers!!

Comment: thank you, i can fix it now. Can you tell me where is the vote button 
i see this is a comment and i cant vote for it

Comment: up arrow above accept answer check mark is upvote button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Just add this line before your onCheckChanged() event like this.

```
viewHolder.nameEn.setText(countries.get(position).getNameEn());
    viewHolder.nameVi.setText(countries.get(position).getNameVi());
    viewHolder.flag.setImageDrawable(countries.get(position).getFlag());
    viewHolder.check.setChecked(false);
    viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count = 0;
            for (MyCountry country : countries) {
                if(country.isCheck())
                    count++;
            }
            if(isChecked)
            {
                if(activity.actionMode == null || count == 0)//chua co
                activity.actionMode = activity.startActionMode(activity.callback);
                count++;
                country.setCheck(true);
            }
            else
            {
                country.setCheck(false);
                count--;
                if(count == 0)
                    activity.actionMode.finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: you can see it in my source @@"
i cant see the different

Comment: new line is added viewHolder.check.setChecked(false);

Answer (score 1):

You have to just set your listview before    notifyDataSetChanged();

public void dellistview() {
         listviewdata.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

```
    SparseBooleanArray selected = listAdapterData.getCheckedItemPositions();

    if (selected != null) {
        try {

            for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (selected.valueAt(i)) {

                    String str[] = arrList.get(selected.keyAt(i));
                    fmdbAccess.removelistitm(sourceTable, str[1]);
                    if (arrList != null)
                        arrList.remove(str);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        selected.clear();
        arrList = fmdbAccess.getGenricTable(sourceTable, colName);
        if (arrList != null && arrList.size() > 0)
        setListAdapter();

        listAdapterData.notifyDataSetChanged();
      //  finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `android:checked="false"` to `CheckBox` in your xml file please

Comment: i try both solution setchecked(false) and checked="false" but not working
i think the notifydatasetchanged() not return a good result